# Power BI: Slicer to select values in tables

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization

I have a table with products, sale date, value in EUR, and value in USD.
For example:

```
Product     Date    EUR    USD
 table      12/10   100    110
 chair      11/10   300    330
```

I've made a matrix, where products are the columns, the months are the rows, and the values are the sales in USD.

```
Product     table     chair     total
 Oct        110       330       440
```

I'm trying to create a slicer that will allow the summed values in the table to flip between EUR and USD.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to create a new table `CurrencySlicer` to use for a slicer.

```
Currency
--------
EUR
USD
```

Then you can write a measure that reads in the selected slicer value and return different things depending on what's selected.

```
Measure =
VAR Curr = SELECTEDVALUE ( CurrencySlicer[Currency], "USD" )
    // This returns the value from your slicer and defaults to "USD" otherwise.
RETURN
    IF ( Curr = "USD", SUM ( ProductTable[USD] ), SUM ( ProductTable[EUR] ) )
```